# Set fixed render time

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have a question ragarding cycles. I want to render images with different settings (materials, sampling, etc.),
so I can compare differences afterwards.

So I would like to limit the render time to a fixed time for each render (f.ex, 10 minutes for each file) - but I cannot find where to set render time anywhere. Where can I set a limit to rendering time?

Comment: I guess there is not such a setting (time limit), per file or per frame... one brute-force alternative for animations is to set the blend to save as image sequence, and then start your render from a batch file (system script) that kills the blender process after whatever time you wish... not ideal , I agree..

Comment: @cegaton I disagree, samples take different time to render. A glass scene will have much less samples done after 10mins than a diffuse scene for example.

Comment: You could enable progressive refine (render the whole image in one shot, rather than per-tile) and just cancel it after enough time passes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to limit the render time exactly. You must experiment with the number of samples to get an equal render time.